# how can I create sharepoint lists using c# without using DLLs like Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I want to create sharepoint lists using c# without using DLLs like Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Getting these DLLs from the internet is not an option.Is there a way I can connect to sharepoint and create sharepoint lists without using those DLLs?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, You can use the REST API. You can find a sample here: [Working with lists by using REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)